# Speed up parameter testing using Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a time series dataframe with about 10 columns where I am performing manipulations on the time series to return results of strategy data.   I would like to test 2 parameters as they may or may not effect each other.  When tested independently, each run take over 10 sec per unit(over 6.5 hours for the total run) and I'm looking to speed this up..I have been reading about dask and it seems that its the right module to use. 
My current code iterates over each parameter range with a nested loops. I know it can be paralleled as the data per day is mutually exclusive.
Here is the code:

```
amount1=np.arange(.001,.03,.0005)
amount2=np.arange(.001,.03,.0005)


def getResults(df,amount1,amount2):
    final_results=[]
    for x in tqdm(amount1):
        for y in amount2:
            df1=None
            df1=function1(df.copy(), x, y ) #takes about 2sec.
            df1=function2(df1)    #takes about 2sec.
            df1=function3(df1)    #takes about 3sec.
            final_results.append([x,y,df1['results'].iloc[-1]])
    return final_results
```

**UPDATE:**

So it looks like the improvements should come by adjusting the function to remove the iteration from the calls and to create a list of jobs(my understanding.  Here is where I am so far. I probably will need to move my df to a dask dataframe, so that the data can be chunked into smaller pieces.  The question is do I leave the function1,2 and 3 functions as pandas vector manulipulations or do they need to move to complete dask functions?

```
def getResults(df,amount):
    df1=None
    df1=dsk.delayed(function1)(df,amount[0],amount[1] )
    df1=dsk.delayed(function2)(df1)
    df1=dsk.delayed(function2)(df1)
    return [amount[0],amount[1],df1['results'].iloc[-1]]


#Create a list of processes from jobs.  jobs is a list of tuples that replaces the iteration.
processes =[getResults(df,items) for items in jobs]

#Create a process list of results
results=[]
for i in range(len(processes):
    results.append(processes[i])
```

Comment: Do you require an exhaustive test on both ranges? Have you considered sampling at least one of them semi-randomly?

Comment: i wouldn't mind that  Results are being returned to a heatmap so identify a range of values.  are you suggesting grid search?

Comment: You should avoid using dask delayed within dask delayed functions

Comment: thanks i figures that out..i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use either [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-overview.html) or the [concurrent.futures](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html) interface.

Something like the following would probably work well (untested, I recommend that you read the docs referenced above to understand what it's doing).

```
def getResults(df,amount1,amount2):
    final_results=[]
    for x in amount1:
        for y in amount2:
            df1=None
            df1=dask.delayed(function1)(df.copy(), x, y ) 
            df1=dask.delayed(function2)(df1) 
            df1=dask.delayed(function3)(df1) 
            final_results.append([x,y,df1['results'].iloc[-1]])
    return final_results   

out = getResults(df, amount1, amount2)
result = delayed(out).compute()
```

Also, I would avoid calling `df.copy()` if you can avoid it.  Ideally function1 would not mutate input data.

Comment: thanks.  i read and have a better understanding.  I reshuffled the function and put  it above in the update above.

Comment: I am having an issue still with the above now.